# Is there a way to import all functions(using *) from a file without the imports of that file?

Tags: python, function, import

I have two .py files

1. `Helper.py`
2. `SomeClass.py`

lets say for the example that both files import sys

I want to import into `SomeClass.py` the `Helper.py` like this: from helper.py import * (because I need all functions in it)

but I don't want to remove from any of the files the import sys because these two files aren't really go hand by hand.

is there a way to to import * and exclude the imports/from...import of another file?

Comment: I think you might have function(s) with same names in both files. And importing second one overrides the first import. And that's why `from MODULE import *` is not a good idea.

Comment: @MSH Yeah i know that in general `import *` is not a good idea. but In my case It's OK,  I know what I've asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) module.

In your `Helper.py` file, add a line

```py
__all__ = ["foo", "bar"]  # All the objects you want to export
```

Then in `SomeClass.py` just use `from helper.py import *`, this will only import what is specified in `__all__`.

Comment: >Cool , didn't know this.